# SLComposeViewController subviews is empty (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, social-framework

I am trying to add "reply" functionality to a particular tweet via SLComposerViewController.

I need to loop through all the subviews and grab the send button as it shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815180/is-there-a-way-of-replying-to-a-particular-tweet-via-slcomposerviewcontroller)

```
SLComposeViewController* tweetViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];   
for (UIView * subview in tweetViewController.view.subviews){
///
}
```

but the subviews is empty. and I couldn't garb the send button. Any clue is much appreciated!

Any other suggestions to have reply functionality for iOS 8 other than using Social framework? I had DETweetComposeViewController before.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the button exactly? subviews is likely empty because the view hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to dig around the private view structure of standard iOS view controllers/views. Such code is fragile and likely to break in future iOS updates.

Comment: So I need a way of replying to a particular tweet via SLComposerViewController and social framework. Is there any better way to implement the reply.