# SLComposeViewController get the user that made the tweet and the message tweeted

Tags: ios, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

I really want to use the iOS social framework and SLComposeViewController to tweet from my app but I need the twitter handle of the user tweeting and the tweet text on the completion (without me fetching latest tweets from all of users twitter accounts and detecting which one he used).

Can I achieve this? If not, is there a good alternative for a textView with twitter handle autocomplete, character counter and twitter account selection?

Comment: did you find a solution? Looking for a solution :)

Comment: @Sam, sadly, no. Please let me know / answer this question if you figure it out. Thanks